Regular tetrahedron face down on a plane: angle between edge and line perpendicular to plane

What is the angle Obase-D-A in the diagram?
(I'm NOT looking for the 109.5 from organic chemistry (AOD). I need one of the other two angles in that triangle.)
Given a regular tetrahedron with one face flat on a plane (ABC),
what is the angle between the tetrahedron's edge and a line perpendicular to the plane defined by face ABC.
Note: I am a sculptor, not a mathematician or an experienced user of math.stackexchange. I apologize for any mistakes or boundary violations.
Thanks.

Should be $35.25$ degrees if your $\angle{AOD}$ is correct.

You might not be a mathematician, but you do know how to make beautiful designs :-)

Let the side length of the tetrahedron be $1$. Note that since $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral, we have $AO_{\text{base}}=\frac{AM}{\cos(30^{\circ})}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.
Hence, $\angle O_{\text{base}}DA=\arcsin\left(\frac{AO_{\text{base}}}{AD}\right)=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)\approx 35.264^\circ$
